# What are the possible causes of `not enough signers`

Tags: anchor, transactions, anchor-client, signature

I am trying to send a transaction with `anchorPY` but I receive a `solders.SignerError: not enough signers`. I can't find information about solders or when that error occurs. I am preparing the transaction and sending `tx.sign(keypair)`

Comment: please provide code associated with constructing and sending the transaction

Answer (score 3):

**What it means**

The program you called requires accounts to sign the transaction. The transaction you crafted and sent does not include all of them.

**Possible causes**

At the very least the fee payer needs to sign, so in your case likely your local wallet/keypair.

Classic mistakes I can think of:

- the one keypair you passed as signer is wrong
- you forgot additional signers (double-check the program endpoint/accounts struct if it's an Anchor program)
- you are **creating an account** through this transaction, in which case you need to pass the account's keypair as a signer in addition to the fee payer